# How to generate Child keys by Parents keys in Array

Tags: javascript

JavaScript ninjas! Now i have this collection:

```
var cats = [
    { id: 1, parent_id: 0, title: 'Movies' },
    { id: 2, parent_id: 0, title: 'Music' },
    { id: 3, parent_id: 1, title: 'Russian movies' },
    { id: 4, parent_id: 2, title: 'Russian music' },
    { id: 5, parent_id: 3, title: 'New' },
    { id: 6, parent_id: 3, title: 'Top10' },
    { id: 7, parent_id: 4, title: 'New' },
    { id: 8, parent_id: 4, title: 'Top10' },
    { id: 9, parent_id: 0, title: 'Soft' }
];
```

And i need this result:

```
var catsExtended = [
    { id: 1, parent_id: 0, childs: [ 3, 5, 6 ], title: 'Movies' },
    { id: 2, parent_id: 0, childs: [ 4, 7, 8 ], title: 'Music' },
    { id: 3, parent_id: 1, childs: [ 5, 6 ], title: 'Russian movies' },
    { id: 4, parent_id: 2, childs: [ 7, 8 ], title: 'Russian music' },
    { id: 5, parent_id: 3, childs: [], title: 'New' },
    { id: 6, parent_id: 3, childs: [], title: 'Top10' },
    { id: 7, parent_id: 4, childs: [], title: 'New' },
    { id: 8, parent_id: 4, childs: [], title: 'Top10' },
    { id: 9, parent_id: 0, childs: [], title: 'Soft' }
];
```

Help me pleace to collect all IDs

Comment: Show us what you tried padawan!

Comment: `parent_id: 0`, but there’s no `id: 0`… why is that? Also, the correct pulral would be `children`.

Comment: Why does the object with `id: 1` have `childs: [3, 5, 6]` despite only the object with `id: 3` having the `parent_id: 1`? You also wouldn’t call your grand-parents parents, now would you?

Comment: parent_id eq zero because it's a clean item

Comment: 3, 5, 6 because 5 and 6 is childs of 3

Comment: BTW it's children not childs.

Comment: @Xufox This is a [Hierarchical data structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_database_model). In this structure `parentID = 0` ( or `null` or other false values) means the node is root and has no parent.

Comment: Yes, that nodes has no parents. Sorry, my english is not perfect :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a hash table for the reference to the already returned objects. And for the parents just iterate until `parent_id` becomes zero.

```js
var cats = [{ id: 1, parent_id: 0, title: 'Movies' }, { id: 2, parent_id: 0, title: 'Music' }, { id: 3, parent_id: 1, title: 'Russian movies' }, { id: 4, parent_id: 2, title: 'Russian music' }, { id: 5, parent_id: 3, title: 'New' }, { id: 6, parent_id: 3, title: 'Top10' }, { id: 7, parent_id: 4, title: 'New' }, { id: 8, parent_id: 4, title: 'Top10' }, { id: 9, parent_id: 0, title: 'Soft' }],
    catsExtended = cats.map(function (a) {
        var id = a.parent_id;
        this[a.id] = { id: a.id, parent_id: a.parent_id, children: [], title: a.title };
        while (id) {
            this[id].children.push(a.id);
            id = this[id].parent_id;
        }
        return this[a.id];
    }, Object.create(null));

console.log(catsExtended);
```

Answer (score 1):

Combine [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```
var catsExtended = cats.map(function(cat) {
    return {
      id: cat.id,
      parent_id: cat.parent_id,
      title: cat.title,
      childs: cats.filter(function(c) {
        return c.parent_id == cat.id;
      }).map(function(c) {
        return c.id
      })
    };
});
```

Comment: Shorter one-liner: `var catsExtended = cats.map(a => (a.children = cats.filter(b => b.parent_id == a.id).map(b => b.id), a));`.

Comment: @Xufox, **1)** This will mutate the source object. **2)** The question is not tagged with ES6.

Comment: this doesn't return the OP's expected result. For example, the first object from your result is `{
        "id": 1,
        "parent_id": 0,
        "title": "Movies",
        "childs": [
            3
        ]
    }`

Comment: Thank you for your variant, but it's not exactly what i want. I want to include childs of childs. Object with id: 1 have childs: [ 3, 5, 6 ] because 5 and 6 are childs of 3. It's the main problem that i want to resolve...

Answer (score 0):

I think a simple `Array.prototype.forEach` can do a lot.

```js
var cats = [{ id: 1, parent_id: 0, title: 'Movies' }, { id: 2, parent_id: 0, title: 'Music' }, { id: 3, parent_id: 1, title: 'Russian movies' }, { id: 4, parent_id: 2, title: 'Russian music' }, { id: 5, parent_id: 3, title: 'New' }, { id: 6, parent_id: 3, title: 'Top10' }, { id: 7, parent_id: 4, title: 'New' }, { id: 8, parent_id: 4, title: 'Top10' }, { id: 9, parent_id: 0, title: 'Soft' }];

cats.forEach(function(c) {
  var pid = c.parent_id;
  c.children = (this[c.id] = this[c.id] || []);
  (this[pid] = (this[pid] || [])).push(c.id)
}, Object.create(null));

console.clear();
console.log(cats);
```